# How to keep running a query to check database all the time every minute in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a project which is a website. Basically it will set a reminder and notify the user using email/SMS. I am using PHP and JavaScript. My database stores the the list of users in table 1 and a separate table for each user and his tasks(with the time and dates). I want to refer the database every minute to check for tasks even if the user is not logged in(browser is closed). What do i do to keep running the check for query all the time?
I want something that will run in background all the time even if user never opens the browser.
Please help.
The php code to store in a users database is

```
<?php
include("init.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $event = $_POST["event"];
    $time = $_POST["time"];
    $daily = $_POST["daily"];
    $weekly = $_POST["weekly"];
    $monthly  = $_POST["monthly"];
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
    $sql = "insert into $fname(fname,date,event,time,daily,weekly,monthly) values('$fname','$date','$event','$time','$daily','$weekly','$monthly')";

    if(mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
        echo "<br><h3> row inserted...</h3>done";
    else
        echo "Error in insertion...".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

There is no issue with the code.
I just need to know how and using what can i refer the database all the time at the server end when user is not on the page.
Can php work 24hrs even if the browser is closed because i know javascript wont work.

Comment: You need to rethink this idea. If the browser is not open or not on the current page then the code will not be able to run. If you want to run this regardless of the browser you might want to look at cron jobs and database timers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event in MySQL (or the database manager you are using, for example:

```
CREATE EVENT e_totals
->     ON SCHEDULE AT '2006-02-10 23:59:00'
->     DO INSERT INTO test.totals VALUES (NOW());
```

Or a recurrent event:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Saves total number of sessions then clears the table each day'
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO site_activity.totals (time, total)
          SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, COUNT(*)
            FROM site_activity.sessions;
        DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
      END |

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sagar what you are looking for is CRON Task. I am afraid that PHP and Javascript alone can't trigger it.

Work flow:

1. Make an API containing all your business logic or processing you need to execute it.
2. Register a CRON job in cPanel or crontab -e in your linux machine.
3. Use the end point directly using AJAX calls or make a separate end point as cron task will continue working.

Refer to this link in case you want to learn more about cron jobs - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples

Thanks,
Abhishek Jain

Comment: Yes, a cron task is definitely the right approach. @Sagar, in case you are not running your own server for the web application you can revert to a web based service like webcron.org to trigger your PHP script. I have been using this service for many years.

Comment: @Sagar, with regards to my earlier comment: the web service is cheap if you don't trigger it too often, but for doing things "every minute" it will probably be a little expensive ...

Comment: i am using windows and not linux. Also for hosting my website i am using [hostinger.in]

Comment: So how do i go about with it @cars10

Comment: i am a newbie so this is all very difficult to understand can you please be more clear

Comment: @Sagar as I can see that free plan (https://www.hostinger.in/free-hosting) includes cron, so I am assuming cron job can be registered easily there.

**To run desired cron job, you need to make sure that your .php file is publicly accessible via your website. When that works, you simply need to enter the file name into the cron job form and choose time settings, the job will be run at specified intervals.**


`Source - https://www.hostinger.in/knowledge-base/50`

Comment: But i am using windows so it tells me to use windows task scheduler.

Comment: Sorry but I am not a Windows user.http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00487/0/Setup-Cron-job-on-Windows-7-Vista-2008.html